# how to get/set char array?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to sort 2 values in char array and read them back. no error/warnings on compile. but the program crashes on startup?

```
#define s_size 9

struct _struct {
public:

    void SetItemName(int i, char *c) {
        strcpy(item[i], c);
    }

    const char *GetItemName(int i) const {
        return item[i];
    }
private:
    char* item[s_size];
};
_struct mystruct;




void Getvalue()
{
    printf(mystruct.GetItemName(0));
}

void Setvalue( )
{
    mystruct.SetItemName(0,"hello");
    mystruct.SetItemName(1,"world");
    Getvalue();
}
```

Comment: You didn't allocate any memory for `item`. Look up `malloc` and research heap memory.

Comment: @David, testing should be mystruct

Comment: @Dave better yet: use `std::vector<std::string>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [modern C++ style](http://klmr.me/slides/modern-cpp/#1), thus `std::vector<std::string>`.

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

struct {
public:
    void SetItemName(std::size_t i, std::string s) {
        if (i >= items.size()) {
            items.resize(i + 1);
        }
        items[i] = std::move(s);
    }

    std::string const& GetItemName(std::size_t i) const {
        return items[i];
    }

private:
    std::vector<std::string> items;
} mystruct;
```

This will do memory management for you, as well as resizing the vector of strings and inserting empty strings if there are any gaps.

Comment: Well I can't, my embedded system compiler do not support modern C++

Comment: @Power-Mosfet Just replace `std::move(s)` with `s` and it should work.

Comment: @Power-Mosfet And, why didn't you inform us in the question?

Comment: The question is too localized then!

Comment: No, a poster preferring to stick with their architecture of solution, and refusing to change to your drastically different one does not make the question "too localized" - regardless if that decision is driven by preference or technical requirement of the platform.